# Does branch-and-bound always achieve a globally optimal solution?

Tags: proof-verification, optimization

I read from some references that the branch-and-bound algorithm will always obtain a globally optimal solution (not suboptimal, not local, or not approximate  solution). Is that true? How to prove that?

Comment: For integer problems, or branch-and-bound in general, taking into account numerical precision for continuous problems?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I do not get about numerical precision for continuous problems means. In B&B, especially in binary problems, usually we relax the binary into $0 \leq x \leq 1$, right?

Comment: Along the process you typically solve linear programs or similar problems, and those are solved numerically, meaning that you face all problems that can arise there numerically. Since you cannot even solve the relaxations exactly, you cannot solve the original problem exactly. In practice though, it typically does not influence much, for reasonably well-defined probems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of branch and bound is almost close to brute force search.

We keep splitting the search space, and work on the subproblems. The bounding part of the algorithm stop us from exploring a branch only if it is proven to not consist of the optimal solution.

Since we do not discard any potential global optimal, we will find one if it exists.

Comment: It means that B&B always achieves a global optimal solution at the end? Do you know how to prove the global optimal solution of B&B? I heard about optimality tolerance $\epsilon$, could we say that B&B obtains $\epsilon$-optimality?

Comment: what is branch and bound to you? how do you do bounding?

Comment: For minimization problem, if we have a feasible solution (all binary and current objective value is less than upper bound), we use the upper bound as the objective value and lower bound when we branch into two subproblems (relaxed variables), right?

Comment: so we only stop exploring a branch if we are sure there is no optimal solution there right?

Comment: Yes, we just prune it. Then the global optimal solution is achieved if we finish checking unpruned nodes (if the solution exists)? Sometimes I confuse with approximate and an upper/lower bound optimal solution of the algorithm.

Comment: in terms of $\epsilon$-optimality, it can be programmed as the termination condition right. For integer problem, since we explore all branches, we will encounter the global solution right.

Comment: That is why, the B&B will always attain a globally optimal solution (especially for MILP, MINLP, or ILP), right?

Comment: yes but the computational time can be exponential.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer, we will always get the global optimum (not taking into account the time needed to get there).

The idea is that we try and find an integer feasible solution and search the tree if and only if the current node's fractional solution has a potential to improve the current best integer solution.

If it can't yield a better integer solution (current node's fractional solution is **worse** than the best integer solution), there is no need to continue exploring past the current node, as adding boundary constraints will necessary worsen the solution.

If it can yield a better integer solution (if the current node's fractional solution is **better** than the current best integer solution), we continue branching until we either find a better integer solution, the problem becomes infeasible or the fractional solution can no longer improve on the current best integer solution.

This means that we can think of it as looking at all of the possible solutions which have the potential to improve on the current solution.

As other commenters noted, we can think of it as a smart brute force algorithm.